# MarkLogic rollback multiple statements explicitCommit

Tags: marklogic, commit, rollback

```
1. declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true});
*************************************************** 
2. let failSafe = [];
3. xdmp.save(ARTIFACT_DIR + 'Geography-1.0-conv.xqy', es.instanceConverterGenerate(geoDesc));
4. failSafe.push("Geography baseline converter module is generated!");
5. xdmp.save(ARTIFACT_DIR + 'GISHealth-1.0-conv.xqy', es.instanceConverterGenerate(gisDesc));
6. failSafe.push("GISHealth baseline converter module is generated!");
7. xdmp.commit(); 
8. failSafe;
```

L5 is expected to fail as: *XDMP-AS: $model as map:map -- Invalid coercion: null as map:map*. 
I am wondering how to achieve this: L3 and L5 must succeed(commit) or fail(rollback) at the same time.  L3 doesn't rollback even L5 fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions are managed only for persistence within the database.

`xdmp.save()` saves to the file system of the local E-node, which is not transactional or shared across the cluster.

By contrast, `xdmp.documentInsert()` does insert within the database. The database operations are buffered until the main module finishes, at which point all of the operations are by default applied in a single transaction.

Thus, in the example above, explicit transactions wouldn't be needed. Either both document inserts would succeed or neither would succeed.

Explicit transactions are useful for keeping a transaction open for additional work in a different invocation of the same main module or a different main module.  Where possible, explicit transactions should be avoided because of the additional complexity, necessity for host affinity from the client, and so on.

Is it possible that `xdmp.documentInsert()` could meet your requirements?  For instance, by inserting the XQuery modules in the content database for later download to a project directory on another system?

Hoping that helps,

Comment: The disk-saved module will be customised to conform the ingesting data to my entity models for data harmonisation purpose. Then it can be inserted into module database to generate other artifacts. It is good to know that not all of xdmp can be treated as transaction.

Comment: It should be fine to insert the pre-customized modules in a database and retrieve the modules from the database.  Just don't save them with execute permissions.  That way the modules won't be executable.  Yes, in my understanding, the file system is not transactional in most file systems. MarkLogic doesn't try to simulate transactions in the file system.